# Need help in Proofwiki of Axiom of choice implies Zorn's Lemma

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I don't understand some point in [proofwiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom_of_Choice_Implies_Zorn%27s_Lemma). (Here is link to the [current revision](http://www.proofwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Axiom_of_Choice_Implies_Zorn%27s_Lemma&oldid=106803) of the ProofWiki article.)

Firstly, it introduces $\mathbb{X}$ be the set of all chains in $(X,\preceq)$ while  $\mathbb{X}$ itself is (partially) ordered by $\subseteq$. And also $\mathbb{S}=\{\bar s(x):x\in X\}$, $\bar s(x)=\{y\in X:y\preceq x\}$. Why each set in $\mathbb{X}$ is dominated by some set in $\mathbb{S}$ ?

Secondly, I think that if there is a set (partially) ordered by $\subseteq$ and take one of its chain, namely $\mathcal{C}$. Is that mean every element in $\mathcal{C}$ orders like '$A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_3\subseteq A_4 ...\subseteq A_n$' If it is, then $\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{C}}A=A_n$ and which is of cause belongs to the original partially ordered set. Why when the proofwiki introduce Tower $\mathcal{T}$, it emphasis that (3): If $\mathcal{C}$ is a chain in $\mathcal{T}$, then $\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{C}}A\in\mathcal{T}$ and when later it introduce $\mathcal{U}$, it says from the definition of $\mathcal{U}$, it follows immediately that the union of a chain in $\mathcal{U}$ is also in $\mathcal{U}$.

Thirdly, Why if  $\mathcal{T}_0$ is the intersection of all towers in $\mathbb{X}$, then  $\mathcal{T}_0$ is the smallest twoer in $\mathbb{X}$?

Lastly, when it comes to conclusion that $\mathcal{U}$ is also a tower and the mapping $g$ maps comparable sets to comparable sets, I don't understand the next statement:

Since the union of a chain of comparable sets is itself comparable, it follows that the comparable sets all form a tower $\mathcal{T}_C$.
But by the nature of $\mathcal{T}_0$ it follows that $\mathcal{T}_0\subseteq \mathcal{T}_C$.
So the elements of $\mathcal{T}_0$ must all be comparable.

Comment: I suggest you migrate your question to the relevant discussion page on ProofWiki.

Comment: I have to admit that this sort of Bourbaki-Witt approach to Zorn's lemma is really a backwards use of the axiom of choice in this proof.

Comment: Actually I am really stuck with the second question. Since I always think of union of chain ordered by $\subseteq$ must be in the original poset. But seems that it isn't

Comment: @AsafKaragila: FYI, that proof appears to me to smash together the proofs of a few different classical AC equivalents into one rambling mess. What approach do you prefer?

Comment: @dfeuer: Transfinite recursion+the existence of a Hartogs number (which is essential for claiming that the recursion halts and we come by a maximal element).

Comment: @UnemChan: You're thinking about finite unions, which is fine. But most things in set theory are not finite.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think I'm finally starting to understand your comment. I'm going to try writing that proof up and I hope you'll be willing to check it.

Comment: @Asaf: Unem Chan may also have some of the same problem with $\text{Pr}\infty\text{fWiki}$ that I have: I find the house style almost unreadably opaque.

Comment: @Brian: Which is why I hinted in my first comment that I dislike this sort of approach anyway. I tried to write an answer, but it took too much time, and I have to attend duties that I had neglected during the semester (i.e. grading homework papers).

Comment: @Asaf: The best thing about retirement is no more grading — even better than no more meetings!

Comment: @Brian: It is said that Iraqi-descendant Israelis hit the mental retirement age around 27. I'm already 28...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm not seeing where Hartogs' lemma comes in. Isn't assuming that every nonempty chain has an upper bound and every element has a successor enough to get an injection from the ordinal class into the set using transfinite recursion, at which point Burali-Forti establishes a contradiction?

Comment: @dfeuer: Your reasoning is correct, albeit over-simplified. The Burali-Forti paradox establishes that the class of ordinals is a proper class. But in order to show that there is no injection from the whole class of ordinals into a set you have to argue more, you have to argue that in that case the power set maps onto the ordinals and use replacement; or that the power set contains a copy of the ordinals by separation proper. From this, however, to Hartogs theorem you just have to argue that if not ordinals are mapped into a set, then there is a least one.

Comment: Replacement should do it trivially, no? If there's an injection from $\operatorname{On}$ to $S$, then that restricts to a bijection whose inverse breaks replacement.

Comment: @dfeuer: If there is no injection from the ordinals into $S$, then there exists a first ordinal from which there is no injection into $S$. The additional claim is a trivial consequence, and we get Hartogs theorem. So while we're at it, we may as well prove it in full.

Comment: I'm just failing to understand how taking that extra step simplifies this proof. Perhaps I would understand it better if I understood just how you suggest using Hartogs'.

Comment: @dfeuer: Hartogs theorem comes in to argue that the recursion has to run into a maximal element at some point. Yes, this is equivalent to saying that there is no injection from the ordinals into $S$. But then again, so is Hartogs' theorem. And since Hartogs' construction is quite useful in other contexts too, one might as well prove that result instead.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: How's http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom_of_Choice_Implies_Zorn%27s_Lemma/Proof_2 look?

Comment: I've added link to the [revision](http://www.proofwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Axiom_of_Choice_Implies_Zorn%27s_Lemma&oldid=106803) of the article at the time of posting the question. (It is quite probable that it will be further edited.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, remember the hypothesis of Zorn’s lemma: every chain in $\langle X,\preceq\rangle$ has an upper bound in $X$. Thus, if $C\in\Bbb X$, there is an $x\in X$ such that $y\preceq x$ for each $y\in C$. But then $C\subseteq\overline{s}(x)\in\Bbb S$ by the definition of $\overline{s}$.

For your second question, suppose that $C\in\Bbb X$: $C$ is a chain in $\langle X,\preceq\rangle$. In particular, $C$ is a subset of $X$. Thus, $\Bbb X\subseteq\wp(X)$, and it makes sense to talk about the partial order $\langle\Bbb X,\subseteq\rangle$. If $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain in this partial order, and $C_1,C_2\in\mathscr{C}$, then either $C_1\subseteq C_2$ or $C_2\subseteq C_1$: that’s what it means to say that $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain in $\langle\Bbb X,\subseteq\rangle$. This does not guarantee, however, that $\bigcup\mathscr{C}$ belongs to the chain $\mathscr{C}$.

> In $\langle\wp(\Bbb R),\subseteq\rangle$, for instance, $\left\{\left[\frac1n,1\right]:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ is a chain of sets, but the union of this chain is the set $(0,1]$, which is not in the chain.

All that we can say for sure is that $\bigcup\mathscr{C}\in\Bbb X$, i.e., that $\bigcup\mathscr{C}$ is a chain in $\langle X,\preceq\rangle$. (To see this, suppose that $x,y\in\bigcup\mathscr{C}$. Then there are $C_1,C_2\in\mathscr{C}$ such that $x\in C_1$ and $y\in C_2$. Since $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain, either $C_1\subseteq C_2$, or $C_2\subseteq C_1$. Without loss of generality suppose that $C_1\subseteq C_2$. Then $x,y\in C_2$, and since $C_2$ is a chain in $\langle X,\preceq\rangle$, either $x\preceq y$ or $y\preceq x$. Thus, $x$ and $y$ in $\bigcup\mathscr{C}$ are comparable, and by definition $\bigcup\mathscr{C}$ is a chain in $\langle X,\preceq\rangle$.)

The same is true for any $\mathscr{T}\subseteq\Bbb X$: if $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain in $\langle\mathscr{T},\subseteq\rangle$, then $\bigcup\mathscr{C}\in\Bbb X$, but we have no guarantee that $\bigcup\mathscr{C}$ actually belongs to $\mathscr{T}$. That’s why the definition of *tower* includes clause $(3)$: we only want to consider those subsets $\mathscr{T}$ of $\Bbb X$ that **do** contain the unions of their chains.

For your third question, let $\Bbb T$ be the set of all towers in $\Bbb X$, and let $\mathscr{T}_0=\bigcap\Bbb X$. We have to show two things: that $\mathscr{T}_0$ is a tower in $\Bbb X$, and that if $\mathscr{T}$ is any tower in $\Bbb X$, then $\mathscr{T}_0\subseteq\mathscr{T}$. To see that $\mathscr{T}_0$ is a tower in $\Bbb X$, we must simply verify that it satisfies the three properties defining towers.

1. $\varnothing\in\mathscr{T}$ for each $\mathscr{T}\in\Bbb T$, so $\varnothing\in\bigcap\Bbb T=\mathscr{T}_0$.
2. If $A\in\mathscr{T}_0$, then $A\in\mathscr{T}$ for each $\mathscr{T}\in\Bbb T$, and therefore $g(A)\in\mathscr{T}$ for each $\mathscr{T}\in\Bbb T$. But then $g(A)\in\bigcap\Bbb T=\mathscr{T}_0$, as desired.
3. If $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain in $\mathscr{T}_0$, then $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain in $\mathscr{T}$ for each $\mathscr{T}\in\Bbb T$, and therefore $\bigcup\mathscr{C}\in\mathscr{T}$ for each $\mathscr{T}\in\Bbb T$. But then $\bigcup\mathscr{C}\in\bigcap\Bbb T=\mathscr{T}_0$, as desired.

Now we know that $\mathscr{T}_0$ is a tower in $\Bbb X$. If $\mathscr{T}$ is **any** tower in $\Bbb X$, then $\mathscr{T}_0=\bigcap\Bbb T\subseteq\mathscr{T}$, so $\mathscr{T}_0\subseteq\mathscr{T}$. That is, $\mathscr{T}_0$ is a subset of **every** tower in $\Bbb X$; and since $\mathscr{T}_0$ is itself a tower in $\Bbb X$, it is therefore the smallest tower in $\Bbb X$. (Here *smallest* means *smallest in the sense of* $\subseteq$; it is not a statement about cardinality.)

For your final question, recall that at that point in the proof the goal is to show that $\mathscr{T}_0$ is a chain in $\langle\Bbb X,\subseteq\rangle$. We’ve defined an element $C\in\mathscr{T}_0$ to be *comparable* if it’s comparable (with respect to $\subseteq$) with each element of $\mathscr{T}_0$, i.e., if for each $A\in\mathscr{T}_0$, either $A\subseteq C$ or $C\subseteq A$. We’ve proved that if $C\in\mathscr{T}_0$ is comparable, it actually satisfies a stronger statement: for each $A\in\mathscr{T}_0$, either $A\subseteq C$, or $g(C)\subseteq A$. (This is stronger because $A\subseteq g(A)$ for each $A\in\Bbb X$, so if $g(C)\subseteq A$, then certainly $C\subseteq A$.) But then for each $A\in\mathscr{T}_0$, either $A\subseteq C\subseteq g(C)$, or $g(C)\subseteq A$, and by definition $g(C)$ is comparable. If $\mathscr{T}_C=\{C\in\mathscr{T}_0:C\text{ is comparable}\}$, this shows that $g(C)\in\mathscr{T}_C$ whenever $C\in\mathscr{T}_C$. And since $\varnothing$ is certainly comparable, $\mathscr{T}_C$ satisfies the first two requirements to be a tower in $\Bbb X$.

Suppose that we can show that $\mathscr{T}_C$ also satisfies the third requirement and is therefore a tower in $\Bbb X$. Then on the one hand we’ll have $\mathscr{T}_C\subseteq\mathscr{T}_0$, but on the other hand we know that $\mathscr{T}_0$ is a subset of **every** tower in $\Bbb X$, so we’ll have $\mathscr{T}_0\subseteq\mathscr{T}_C$. Thus, $\mathscr{T}_C=\mathscr{T}_0$. But that means that every element of $\mathscr{T}_0$ is comparable: for any $C\in\mathscr{T}_0$, $C$ is comparable, so for any $A\in\mathscr{T}_0$, either $C\subseteq A$ or $A\subseteq C$. And that means iprecisely that $\langle\mathscr{T}_0,\subseteq\rangle$ is a chain.

All that’s missing, then is to verify that $\mathscr{T}_C$ satisfies the third condition on towers: if $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain in $\mathscr{T}_C$, then $\bigcup\mathscr{C}\in\mathscr{T}_C$. Suppose, then that $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain in $\mathscr{T}_C$, and let $C=\bigcup\mathscr{C}$. $\mathscr{T}_C\subseteq\mathscr{T}_0$, so $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain in $\mathscr{T}_0$. $\mathscr{T}_0$ is a tower, so $C\in\mathscr{T}_0$. To complete the proof, we need to show that $C$ is comparable, so that $C\in\mathscr{T}_C$.

Let $A\in\mathscr{T}_0$ be arbitrary; we want to show that either $A\subseteq C$ or $C\subseteq A$. Suppose that there is a $C_1\in\mathscr{C}$ such that $A\subseteq C_1$; then $A\subseteq C_1\subseteq\bigcup{C}=C$. If there is no such $C_1$, then $C_1\subseteq A$ for each $C_1\in\mathscr{C}$. (Remember that every $C_1\in\mathscr{C}$ is comparable, so if $A\nsubseteq C_1$, then $C_1\subseteq A$.) But then $C=\bigcup\mathscr{C}=\bigcup_{C_1\in\mathscr{C}}C_1\subseteq A$. Thus, either $A\subseteq C$, or $C\subseteq A$, and $C$ is indeed comparable.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But when [zorn's lemma implies axiom of choice](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_Lemma_Implies_Axiom_of_Choice), it suppose the lemma hold. If it can't be easily guarantee union of set is in the chain (in this case, extension of function, I think they are similar), why it guarantee all the chains has upper bound? and why if g is maximum, Dom(g) equal to power set of X not empty?

Comment: @UnemChan: If $A\in(\wp(X)\setminus\{\varnothing\})\setminus\operatorname{Dom}g$, pick any $x\in A$, and let $g'=g\cup\{\langle A,x\rangle\}$; then $g\prec g'$, and $g'\in\mathscr{F}$, contradicting the maximality of $g$. Thus, $\operatorname{Dom}g$ must be all of $\wp(X)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$. The answer to your first question is that the union of any chain in $\mathscr{F}$ is an element of $\mathscr{F}$; just check that it has each of the three required properties.

Comment: @M.Scott: sorry border you again, but there is still a problem of question 1 which I don't understand. The aim of the proof is to find out the maximal set in $\mathbb{S}$, but how come it only proves that there is a maximal set in $\mathbb{X}$. It said that each set in $\mathbb{X}$ is dominated by some set in $\mathbb{S}$, but what is the meaning of "going from $\mathbb{S}$ to $\mathbb{X}$ cannot introduce any new maximal elements"?

Comment: @UnemChan: Suppose that $C\in\Bbb X$; $C$ is a chain in $\langle X,\preceq\rangle$. Then $\{\overline{s}(x):x\in C\}$ is a chain in $\langle\Bbb S,\subseteq\rangle$. By hypothesis every chain in $\Bbb S$ has an upper bound in $\Bbb S$, so there is an $\overline{s}(z)\in\Bbb S$ such that $\overline{s}(x)\subseteq\overline{s}(z)$ for each $x\in C$. But then $x\preceq z$ for each $x\in C$, so $z$ is an upper bound for $C$ in $X$. It follows that $C\subseteq\overline{s}(z)$. Thus, if $C$ is a maximal element of $\Bbb X$, $\overline{s}(z)$ is a maximal element of $\Bbb S$. The key fact here is ...

Comment: ... that for any $x,y\in X$, $x\preceq y$ if and only if $\overline{s}(x)\subseteq\overline{s}(y)$.